# Validation and prediction Accuracy of VGG19 Model is not getting better

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, vgg-net

Hello I am working on detecting diabetic retinopathy from images in the kaggle dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection) using VGG19, I have pre processed my images with a gaussian filter and resizing them to 224 x 224 x 3 an then I passed them to a vgg19 model with training images = 5760 and validation images = 640. I am getting a training accuracy of 100% but the validation accuracy is not getting better than 60% and the prediction accuracy after the model finished is 50%.
This is my model code:

```
    for count in range(6):
    print("*************************************************************************************************")
    print("******************************************************Fold " + str(count))

    trainDirectory = "Folds/Fold" + str(count) + "-Train"
    testDirectory = "Folds/Fold" + str(count) + "-Test"
    trdata = ImageDataGenerator()
    traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(class_mode = 'binary' , batch_size= 64, directory= trainDirectory , target_size=(224, 224))
    tsdata = ImageDataGenerator()
    testdata = tsdata.flow_from_directory(class_mode = 'binary' , batch_size=64, directory= testDirectory, target_size=(224, 224))

    from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
    vggmodel = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

    for layers in (vggmodel.layers)[:19]:
        layers.trainable = False

    X = vggmodel.layers[-2].output
    predictions = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(X)
    model_final = Model(vggmodel.input, predictions)

    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    model_final.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
                        metrics=["accuracy"])

    from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg19_1.h5", monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
    early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=50, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    h = model_final.fit_generator(generator=traindata, steps_per_epoch= int(5760 / 64), epochs= 10 , validation_data=testdata,
                              validation_steps= int(640 / 64) , callbacks=[checkpoint, early])

    modelHistory.append(h.history)
    model_final.save_weights("vgg19_1.h5")
    model_final.save('vgg19_1.h5')
    model = load_model('vgg19_1.h5')

    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


    predict_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

    predict_generator = predict_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        "Validation",
        class_mode= None,
        target_size=(224, 224),
    )

    pred = model.predict_generator(predict_generator)

    y_pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
    print('Confusion Matrix')
    print(confusion_matrix(predict_generator.classes, y_pred))
    print('Classification Report')
    target_names = ['0', '1']
    print(classification_report(predict_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))

    l = len(y_pred)
    acc = sum([y_pred[i]==predict_generator.classes[i] for i in range(l)])/l
    print(acc)
    predictedAccuracy.append(acc)
```

this is the accuracy that I have got:
[image]

this is the plot of the accuracy / loss
[image]

Comment: a plot of the error would be much more useful than the text output

Comment: @VasilYordanov please find attached the image of the training , testing accuracy for my model, the validation accuracy is not improving from 65%

Comment: I meant the output of:


`f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(20,15))`

`ax[0].plot(h.history['loss'], label='train loss')`
`ax[0].plot(h.history['val_loss'], label='val loss')`
`ax[0].set_ylabel('classification loss')`
`ax[0].set_xlabel('epoch')`
`ax[0].grid()`
`ax[0].legend()`

`ax[1].plot(h.history['accuracy'], label='train accuracy')`
`ax[1].plot(h.history['val_accuracy'], label='val accuracy')`
`ax[1].set_ylabel('Accuracy')`
`ax[1].set_xlabel('epoch')`
`ax[1].grid()`
`ax[1].legend()`

Comment: @VasilYordanov I have added the plot to the question if you can help me. Thank you

Comment: did you rescale your inputs?  VGG is designed to have the inputs in the range from -1 to +1.

Comment: Also since the base model is frozen you are only training the dense layer with 1 neuron. I would try train a few of the top layers in the base model and see if performance improves. If not add a dense layer with say 64 neurons then a dropout layer with dropout rate at about .4.

Comment: @GerryP No I didn't rescale the inputs , I will try to rescale them and train some other layers, thank you.

Comment: @GerryP I have put this for my training and testing generator: trdata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, featurewise_center = False , samplewise_center = False, featurewise_std_normalization = False, samplewise_std_normalization = False) It didn't get better , also I have set the first 15 layers in the VGG19 as trainable = False and the last 4 layers as trainable = true but it didn't get better. Any other solution??